# How to deploy an app in Open Shift

Tags: war, web-deployment, openshift

I'm deploying my app to Open Shift hosting, but I cannot do it works.

I did the git add . git commit... git push, and everything was fine.

I remove the pom.xml and I push the war file inside webapps folder.

But when I browse the URL, nothing happens.

This is my link: http://backend-f1987.rhcloud.com/ If I do a clone from another computer, I download the war file correctly, so I don't know where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your war is not ROOT.war then try to access it with http://backend-f1987.rhcloud.com/warName; also check your logs to see for any errors: https://www.openshift.com/faq/how-to-troubleshoot-application-issues-using-logs

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using ROOT.war inside the webapps folder. I get an error 443 when I tried to see the logs. I tried to do rhc tail backend (where backend is my appname)